# Why does the Now In Android app use the NiaAppState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What is the point of the NiaAppState in the Now In android app?

https://github.com/android/nowinandroid

What is the benefit to storing the navcontroller that way? At what point should I use the appstate instead of just passing my navcontroller in my navigation graph through a parameter?